# EntityFramework, Database design Table with nullable foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have this issue with my database design.
I have four tables:**Garments**, **Attachments**, **Images** and **Fonts**.

A **Garment** can have multiple or no **Attachments** so that is easy to map:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Garment>().HasMany(m => m.Attachments).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(m => m.GarmentId);
```

But the complication arrises with **Attachments**. I have read that having multiple **nullable** foreign keys is bad practice, but I can't work out how to map this flow.

An **Attachement** can either have an **Image** OR a **Font**. It can never have both and must have at least one.

My initial class looked like this:

```
public class Attachment
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public int FontId { get; set; }
    [Required] public int GarmentId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] [Required] public string PanelId { get; set; }

    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public Font Font { get; set; }
}
```

but this doesn't enforce anything. Is there anyway way that EF can handle this in a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Entity Framework Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx) and especially `IValidatableObject`

```
public class Attachment : IValidatableObject
{
    //...

    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public Font Font { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
    { 
        if (Image == null && Font == null) 
        { 
            yield return new ValidationResult 
             ("Image or Font must be specified", new[] { "Image", "Font" }); 
        }
        if (Image != null && Font != null) 
        { 
            yield return new ValidationResult 
             ("You cannot provide both an Image and a Font", new[] { "Image", "Font" }); 
        }
    }
}
```

If you really need it and support is provided, you may add a constraint on the data store. For SQL Server, see [CHECK CONSTRAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190377(v=sql.120).aspx).

Comment: what about if it was 4 properties? Surely there is a better design. But if not, I don't want all them if statements :)

Comment: @r3plica you could write a custom `ValidationAttribute`. For a good sample, see `PropertiesMustMatchAttribute`. If you really want to redesign the whole thing, you may have a base class for `Image`, `Font`,... and have a foreign key of the base class.